# How to add comments to statuses (like facebook)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to improve an exercice that I did on treehouse, the idea was to  remake a little version of facebook thing, where users could publish statuses.

Now I want that a user can comment any statuses... And I am kinda lost...
The idea is to have all on the same page (if possible?, like on the real facebook) 
So the comment form and the "displaying" content...

I hope anyone could help me :)
[This is my github repository](https://github.com/knopfler81/treebook)

I think I haven't understand  how to call variables from a controller to another...
If someone could explain me with very easy words ... I am not native english speaker... so sometime it's difficult..

### Here are the statuses part

**controllers/statuses_controller/rb**

```
class StatusesController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!, only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update]
  before_action :set_status, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
   @statuses = Status.all
   @comments = Comment.all
  end

 def show
  @status = Status.find(params[:id])
  @comments = @status.comments.all
 end

 def new
  @status = Status.new
  @comment = @status.comments.build
 end

def create
 @status = Status.new(status_params)
 @status.user = current_user
 respond_to do |format|
   if @status.save
     format.html { redirect_to @status, notice: 'Status was successfully created.' }
     format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @status }
   else
     format.html { render :new }
     format.json { render json: @status.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
   end
 end
end

def update
 respond_to do |format|
  if @status.update(status_params)
    format.html { redirect_to @status, notice: 'Status was successfully updated.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @status }
  else
    format.html { render :edit }
    format.json { render json: @status.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
 end
end

def destroy
 @status.destroy
 respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to statuses_url, notice: 'Status was successfully destroyed.' }
  format.json { head :no_content }
 end
end

private
  def set_status
   @status = Status.find(params[:id])
 end

 def status_params
  params.require(:status).permit(:user_id, :content, :comments_attribute[:id, :status_id, :content])
 end
end
```

**models/status.rb**

```
class Status < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :comments

  default_scope -> { order(created_at: :DESC)}

  validates :content, presence: true,
            length: {minimum: 2}
  validates :user_id, presence: true
end
```

**views/comments/_form.html.erb** I create a render in my index below:

```
<% simple_form_for @status.comments do |f|%>
 <%= f.input :content %>
 <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end  %>
```

**view/statuses/index.html.erb**

```
<div class="page-header">
  <h1>All of the Statuses</h1>
</div>
<%= link_to "Post A New Status", new_status_path, class: "btn btn-success"%>
<br>
<br>
<% @statuses.each do |status| %>

  <div class="status">

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-1 avatar">
        <%= image_tag status.user.avatar.thumb if status.user.avatar?%>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-7">
        <h4><%= status.user.full_name%></h4>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-8">
       <p><%= simple_format(status.content) %></p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-xs-8">
      <%= link_to time_ago_in_words(status.created_at) + " ago", status %>
        <% if status.user == current_user %>
          <span class="admin">
        |   <%= link_to "Edit", edit_status_path(status) %> |
            <%= link_to "Delete", status, method: :delete, data: {confirm: "Are you sure?"} %>
          </span>
        <% end  %>
       </div>
     </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
       <p>Comments</p>

       <% @comments.each do |comment| %>
         <%= comment.content %>
       <% end %>
     </div>
   </div>

   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <%= render "comments/form" %>
    </div>
   </div>

</div>
```

### Now the comments part:

**model/comment.rb**

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :status
 belongs_to :user
end
```

**controllers/comments_controller.rb**
      class CommentsController < ApplicationController

```
  def create
   @comment = Comment.new(params_comment)
  end

  def index
   @statuses = Status.all
   @comments = Comment.all
   @comment = Comment.find_by(params[:id])
  end

 private

 def params_comment
   params.require(:comment).permit(:content)
 end
end
```

**routes.rb**

```
  resources :statuses do
   resources :comments
  end
```

**user.rb**
that's a part of what I have in there

```
  has_many :statuses
  has_many :comments
```

Comment: When looping through your `@statuses` in index, each `status` has its own comments. So instead of rendering *all* comments at *every* status, only display the comments belonging to the status: `status.comments.each do |comment|`

Comment: And what exactly is not working?

Comment: whith status.comments.each do |comment| it says `undefined local variable or method `status' for #<#<Class:......`

Comment: well you have to use it *in* your `@statuses` loop

Comment: it is already in the loop ? the @statuses  <%end %> is at the end of the file?

Comment: Can you show the whole error? you stopped the comment at `#<#<Class...`

Comment: sure: `undefined local variable or method status' for #<#<Class:0x007fb219d51b00>:0x007fb21ca1a5d8>`

Comment: so what exactly is not working?

Comment: Or better: what did work and when did it stop working?

Comment: The form worked once ( but I don't remember how... but when I was commenting a status, the same comment was displaying on all the other statuses....) I really don't remember how I did this...
And now the form isn't reconized anymore because of the errors....
Is there anything in the controllers that I am missing? or in the modes?

Comment: yeah, what I'd suggest is you only work on the show action for now. The variables are fine.. And then you have to delete some code and see if it works, if it doesn't remove some more, until you find the buggy code

Comment: Thanks TheChamp I will try again :)

Comment: when I work in `rails console`I can create a comment to a status_id!so if it works in the console it should work here in the layout... right?

Comment: yes of course, you have messed up somewhere in the code. You should focus on one action iE `show` - and restructure your question

Comment: please have a look on My Edits :) 
I solved some problem, but I need help again

Comment: if you have a new question post a new one...  Also, you should post your solution as an answer, so it has value for future visitors...

Comment: ok you did just that... still, edit out your new question from this one and share your solution, so this post gets value

Comment: I will edit when I have the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

your comments creation method should look like this:

```
@status = Status.find(params[:status_id])
@comment = @status.comments.create(comment_params)
@comment.user_id = current_user.id if current_user
@comment.save
```

Comment: thanks for this :) not yet fixed but step by step I'll get it :)

Comment: Although this code may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain _why_ and/or _how_ it answers the question. Providing this additional context  would significantly improve its long-term educational value. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what limitations and assumptions apply.